# CSS transition won't work on hover

Tags: html, css

I have a news item with an image that I set with a style on the div.  I have it set to decrease on hover which works but the css animation will not work.

In the div class I have added in

```
  background-size: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
```

and in the :hover I have added

```
background-size: 110% !important;
```

Here is a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/atzgL43v/3/

The strange thing is that in the divs style is set to

```
style="background-size: cover; background: url('http://i.imgur.com/ppEjVyF.jpg');
```

But cover doesn't work on the style and also the image won't resize unless I add !important.  Not sure why this isn't working.

Comment: inline styles can be overriden only by using `!important`

Answer (score 1):

A workaround I had was to get rid of all the background-size attributes and set the :hover with the following.

```
.news-tile-img-post:hover {
  -ms-transform: scale(1.1); /* IE 9 */
   -webkit-transform: scale(1.1); /* Safari */
   transform: scale(1.1); /* Standard syntax */
}
```

This then allowed the transitions to work as well as not having to use the !important in the css.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the background-size attribute is not supported for transitions.

See [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#animatable-properties)

Comment: It is animatable...but not when using a keyword llike `cover.`